# Error ''Keyboard' no encontrado' usando una tarjeta RFID para desbloquear mi PC

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy creando un programa en mi `Arduino` Uno el cual quiero que al pasar una tarjeta `RFID` mi pc se desbloquee automáticamente, pero al momento de querer subir el programa a mi `Arduino`, me aparece el siguiente error :

```
Arduino:1.8.9 (Windows 10), Tarjeta:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

F:\Descargas\windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid\windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid.ino: In function 'void setup()':

windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid:16:2: error: 'Keyboard' no encontrado. Tu sketch incluye la línea '#include <Keyboard.h>'?
  Keyboard.begin();

  ^

F:\Descargas\windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid\windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid.ino: In function 'void loop()':

windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid:43:3: error: 'Keyboard' no encontrado. Tu sketch incluye la línea '#include <Keyboard.h>'?
   Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);              //Press the left windows key.

   ^

windows_pc_lock_unlock_using_rfid:43:18: error: 'KEY_LEFT_GUI' was not declared in this scope

   Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);              //Press the left windows key.

                  ^

exit status 1
'Keyboard' no encontrado. Tu sketch incluye la línea '#include <Keyboard.h>'?

Este informe podría contener más información con
"Mostrar salida detallada durante la compilación"
opción habilitada en Archivo -> Preferencias.
```

Y el código que uso es este :

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 5
#define KEY_RETURN 0xB0                 //The hex value for the return key is 0xB0.

MFRC522 mfrc522 ( SS_PIN, RST_PIN ) ;
char Enter = KEY_RETURN;                //Return key is declared as Enter.
String readid;
String card1="48b45a10";                //Change this value to the UID of your card.

void setup( ) 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Keyboard.begin();
 SPI.begin();
 mfrc522.PCD_Init();
}

void temp(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize)//function to store card uid as a string datatype.
{
  readid="";
  for(byte i = 0;i<bufferSize; i++)
  {
    readid=readid+String(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
void loop( ) 
{
 if(!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
 {
  return;
 }
 if(!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
 {
  return;
 }
 mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));  // Display card details in serial Monitor.
 temp(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
 if(readid==card1)
 { 
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);              //Press the left windows key.
  Keyboard.press('l');                       //Press the "l" key.
  Keyboard.releaseAll();                     //Release all keys.
  delay (100);
  Keyboard.press(Enter);                     //Press the Enter key.
  Keyboard.release(Enter);                   //Release the Enter key.
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.print("gatulongo399");                    // Change this value to your Windows PIN/Password.
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.press(Enter);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
 }
 else
 {
  return;
 } 
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este error? El código no es mio, sino que lo saque de una web (https://www.instructables.com/id/Windows-PC-LockUnlock-Using-RFID/)

**Postdata, esto lo estoy intentando adaptar de un Arduino Nano A un Arduino UNO**

Comment: Postdata, esto lo estoy intentando adaptar de un Arduino Nano A un Arduino UNO

Answer (score 0):

pues no se, puede ser incompatible los comandos entre si, pero si mal no me acuerdo, arduino (programa) tiene manera de compilar y verificar, si lo miras luego veras una parte que cambia de color y eso es el error. Pero creo que no permiten ciertos comandos, pero el que abrieses tantos corchetes me ha liado,  ¿que tal si lo simplificas? he visto que hay partes que se pueden quitar o acortar. (yo he usado poco arduino, no te puedo decir mucho mas)

Comment: Sorry, pero no se muy bien simplificar esos codigos